# C# repeat data, reset on boundary

Tags: c#, loops, byte

I'm trying to write some repeated data into a byte array, it looks like this:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("UNKNOWN");

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < several_MB_worth_of_bytes; i++)
{   
    output[i] = bytes[count];
    count++;
    if (count >= bytes.Length) count = 0;
}
```

This works, however, I need to reset the count variable if I've written exactly 1MB worth of bytes, so the next byte after the 1MB boundary will the the first 'U' in the string.  This needs to happen on every MB boundary.

I can't seem to quite figure out the best way of handling the reset.  I've taken a look at the `ByteSize` library for .net, but I'm still not sure how that's going to help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check whether `i` is a multiple of 1 MB inside the same if statement where you are resetting the counter:

```
if (count >= bytes.Length || i % (1024*1024) == 0) count = 0;
```

Comment: i should probably mention that 1MB is not `1024 * 1204` bytes.  that's a [Mebibyte](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) (MiB).  1MB is `1000 * 1000` bytes.

Comment: Looking at this code, it's resetting on 0, and on 1024.

Comment: You should put the statement at the beginning of  the loop then

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb, but 1024 % (1024*1024) is zero, but that's not a megabyte, so I'm missing something?

Comment: you should also close the `1024 * 1024` part in parenthesis, since `%` and `*` have the same precedence.

Comment: Yep, that got it.  Thanks all!

Comment: 1024 % (1024*1024) is 1024. My code just had the parentheses in the wrong place